# Adding a radio button to JQuery buttonset at runtime

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I am trying to add a radio button to a buttonset at runtime.  This is my HTML:

```
<form>
  <div id="container">
    <input type="radio" id="radio1" name="tipo" value="1"/>
    <label for="radio1">Alt1</label>

    <input type="radio" id="radio2" name="tipo" value="2"/>
    <label for="radio2">Alt2</label>   
  </div>
</form>
```

and this is my Javascript:

```
$(function() {
  $("#container").buttonset();
  $("#container").append("<input type='radio' id='radio3' name='tipo' value='3'/><label for='radio3'>Alt3</label>");
  $("#container").buttonset();
})
```

This shows Alt1 and Alt2 in the JQueryUI skin.  Alt3 appears as a normal radio button.  If I comment out the first buttonset like so it works:

```
$(function() {
  //$("#container").buttonset();
  $("#container").append("<input type='radio' id='radio3' name='tipo' value='3'/><label for='radio3'>Alt3</label>");
  $("#container").buttonset();
})
```

It seems that you can only set the buttonset once.  I read elsewhere that you should be able to call:

```
$("#container").buttonset('refresh');
```

But that doesn't work for me.

Has anyone found a way around this?  The above code is a simplified version of what I am trying to do.  I am appending to the container at runtime, and I want the radio buttons to appear as JQueryUI style.  The above code is simplified to show just what the problem is.

You can try it for yourself here:  http://jsfiddle.net/aembleton/vwemc/

Comment: seems like its working (im using Chrome)

Comment: I've just updated the url to http://jsfiddle.net/aembleton/vwemc/  The one before was missing the first buttonset which is why it worked.  I've tested it in Chrome and its also broken in there.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an updated fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/maniator/w6Fec/3/

Here is the code:

```
$(function() {
    $("#container").buttonset();
    $("#container").append("<input type='radio' id='radio3' name='tipo' value='3'/><label for='radio3'>Alt3</label>");
    $("#container").buttonset('refresh');
})
```

For some reason in your fiddle you were using 2 jQueryUI's.

Comment: Thank you very much.  I went back and looked at my actual code and realised that when I tried calling .buttonset('refresh'); I hadn't called .buttonset() before hand which was causing it to fail.